# Changing "background-image:" on a timer using javascript not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if you would mind taking a look at the following code and tell me where I'm going wrong. I know close to nothing about javascript but I was able to some code that is supposed to do what I want. I've got a div ID makes a fullscreen image background. I want to change out what image is used every 5000 milliseconds. Here's the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).load(function() {          
          var i =0;
          var images = ['cover1.jpg','cover2.jpg'];
          var image = $('.cover_image');
          image.css('background-image', 'url(/img/cover1.jpg)');
          setInterval(function(){  
              image.fadeOut(1000, function () {
                  image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images [i++] +')');
                  image.fadeIn(1000);
              });
              if(i == images.length)
              i = 0;
          }, 5000);           
      });
</script>
```

Here's the CSS being used:

```
.cover_image {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url("/img/cover1.jpg");
background-position: bottom center;
background-size: cover;
z-index: -3;
position: relative;
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div class="slide cover_image"></div>
```

Comment: After formatting code it looks like `if (i == images.length)` code doesn't do anything, is `i = 0;` supposed to be in brackets after that `if` check?

Comment: I think you are using the jQuery.load función wrong. It takes a url and a json but instead you are passing a callback. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems here, when you use JQuery, and your *"loop"*

## JQuery Loading

JQuery isn't always loaded at the same time as Javascript. So trying to detect when Javascript is loaded to use JQuery might let you use Javascript code, as soon as you run some JQuery selectors, it'll crash. And burn. So don't do that.

#### Why?

Most modern browsers excuse many Javascript files at once. This means JQuery starts when the document is ready, and your code tries to use the uninitialized JQuery library. This means you use something that's not there. It's like trying to read the end of th

If your only objective was to read the end of that sentence, you would crash, too.

## Zero-Indexed Arrays

Also, I made a change to the way your loop works, because it was somewhat broken. Javascript has 0-indexed arrays, so trying to get the `.length` of an array with 2 elements will return `2`, but the elements are at `[0]` and `[1]`.

#### Why?

It was mainly because computers could started counting at zero, so in the old days, it made no sense to waste a bit (literally), and it was also much more processor intensive to do arithmetic, so starting at zero made sense. We could switch to 1-indexed arrays, like [Lua](http://lua.org) does, but it's still a bit friendlier on computers to start at zero, plus many programmers were used to it, and changing an aspect like that will break older programs.

### Code/TL;DR;

```
$(function(){  
    var i =0;
    var images = ['cover1.jpg','cover2.jpg'];
    var image = $('.cover_image');
    image.css('background-image', 'url(/img/cover1.jpg)');
    setInterval(function(){  
        image.fadeOut(1000, function () {
            image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i] +')');
            image.fadeIn(1000);
        });
        if(i == (images.length - 1)){
            i = 0; 
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }, 5000);
})
```

Comment: "JQuery isn't always loaded at the same time as Javascript" this is silver (almost gold).

Comment: @Knu Think it's Better?

Comment: I follow you as much as my limited knowledge of javascript allows. :) I get what you are saying about using (window).load or at least I get how that's a problem. 

Thanks for rewriting the code. It does kick off this time. The only problem is it doesn't load the next image in the sequence. The first image fades out and another image never loads. I checked and I have the images labeled correctly and in the /img/ folder. Would it be helpful if I linked to the site? If so here it is: http://travelandlifestylephotography.com/test/

Comment: I had to change 

    `image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images[i] +')');`
to 
    `image.css('background-image', 'url(img/' + images[i] +')');`


I found a nifty jquery plugin that does exactly what I need. In case someone stumbles across this thread looking for something similar, here it is: https://github.com/rewish/jquery-bgswitcher#built-in-effect-types

Answer (score -2):

Bootstrap has a "carousel" class that looks great and works without the need for extensive JS. If you don't know what Bootstrap is, I would advise looking it up because I use it on almost all of my webpages. Here's a link to a carousel example: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp